# how can I know file's locale?

Tags: locale, setlocale

I want to read a file(like .txt) and do std::cout.

but if the file's locale doesn't same with my system's locale, it will print weird.

this is my question. how can I know the file's locale?

if I can get file's locale, I can change system's locale to file's locale and it will print clearly.

Comment: Where are you reading the file from? on local file system or from remote source? You would have to just use the appropriate encoding in your reader.

Comment: What is the content of the file? What output are you getting.

Comment: oh sorry.. I'm using C++ .

Comment: and the file is on local file system. and content is just string. I'll just check the file is written with chinese locale, or japanese, etc..

Answer (score 0):

Read file using something like:

new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(...), )

For encoding Use the required encoding based on file source, you can guess that or try UTF-8 for a test.

Example:

```
String file = "file location";
    String encoding = "utf-8";
    try {
        new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), encoding);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        System.out.println("Encoding Uknown " + encoding);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```